# Aggregate Sum based on Condition in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the below query and I would like to find the total number of exams a student has taken in a school year as a **new column** called `totalExamsTaken`

StudentExam table has fields of studentID, examDesc, examGrade, schoolYear
StudentInfo table has fields of studentID, studentName, age, gender

```
StudentInfo
| lookup StudentExams on studentID
| project studentID, studentName, age, gender, examDesc, examGrade, schoolYear
```

In the end I would like to create a table that has columns of `studentID`, `studentName`, `age`, `gender`, `schoolYear`, **totalExamsTaken**.

```
StudentID StudentName Age Gender SchoolYear TotalExamsTaken
 
0001       John Doe    15  Male     2019        13
0001       John Doe    15  Male     2018        19
0001       John Doe    15  Male     2017        15
0002       Jane Doe    16  Female   2019        13
0002       Jane Doe    16  Female   2018        19
0002       Jane Doe    16  Female   2017        12
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this, using the [`lookup` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator):

```
let examCountByStudentId = 
   StudentExams
   | summarize totalExamsTaken = count() by studentId, schoolYear
;
StudentInfo
| lookup examCountByStudentId on studentId
```